# SubSonic 2.2 Left join error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subsonic, left-join

I know this may have been answered but SubSonic 2.2 causes an error in the SQL provider when trying to do a Left join (Left inner join to subsonic)

instead of creating SQl like

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table 2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

it creates:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT INNER JOIN table 2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

and this errors as invalid SQL code.

is there a work around? As i spose you're not supporting it at all anymore?

Comment: >>>As i spose you're not supporting it at all anymore?
Did you want me to answer your question or...?

Comment: Can you post the code that generates this query?

Comment: Sorry Rob i was referring to 2.2 as opposed to 3.x

Comment: The code that generates it is: 

SQlQuery q = new Select().From(Tables.Product).LeftInnerJoin(Product.Columns.CatIdColumn,Categories.Columns.CatIDColumn)              

This is an example but you get the point - i have only every known it to be call a "LEFT JOIN" in SQL not a "LEFT INNER JOIN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting the subsonic mailing list it would appear i simply needed to change the order that my fields where in the inner join, after doing this it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know MSSQL Syntax, but with MySQL there are no "LEFT INNER" or "LEFT OUTER" joins.
However if you change your code to a left outer join, that works (with MySQL)

Comment: this was a comment in regards to the sql generation from SubSonic.